# Construct INSERT statement with values from dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Here is my code:

Created structure that holds headers for my INSERT and their types (varchar, integer, date etc)

```
public struct Values
{
        public string header;
        public string type;
}
```

Created dictionary that holds `int key`, for each key I have corresponding value of `header` and its `type`:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Values>();
```

Then I have `List` of values that i take from Excel file:

```
var l_values = new List<string>();
```

I put headers and their values into predefined INSERT string:

```
var insert = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});";
```

I should add that I put values in places with `String.Format`

Question 1: how can I iterate through values in my `List` so that if put it in my `insert` string they will be put in template format?

For example:

for the first `key` in my dictionary I have **birthdate** `header` and **date** `type` I want to check for the `type` if it is **date** it should put it into `insert` string like this:

```
insert into table_name (birthdate, etc) 
values (TO_DATE('2016/10/02', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), etc);
```

Question 2: if there is no value in `List` to and according `header` in `mydictionary` what to do?

Comment: Why a separate list for the values? Why not adding another field to the Values class that contains the value? In this way if a value is missing you know the associated 'header' (or better field name)

Comment: @Steve I thought it would be easier to manipulate List values without touching Dictionary. Since I get `headers` and their `types` from database and `values` from Excel.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you use ADO.NET ?

Comment: @IlyaMaskov I am using NPOI for Excel and OracleManagedDataAccess.dll, making it all in Web Application

Comment: *OracleManagedDataAccess.dll* is a part of `ODP.NET`. It would be nice to figure out what data access technology you use (it could be `ADO.NET` or `EF`). Could you show us your c# code that already exists?